# Firebase: signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: Second argument "password" must be a valid string

Tags: firebase, typescript, angular-6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Estou obtendo um return **null** para meu segundo parâmetro junto ao metodo signInWithEmailAndPassword. Este erro inibindo minha autenticação.

```
public autenticar(email: string, senha: string): void {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha)
        .then((resposta: any) => {
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
                .then((idToken: string) => {
                    this.token_id = idToken
                    localStorage.setItem('idToken', idToken)
                    this.router.navigate(['/home'])
                })
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error))
}
```

Código do template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="autenticar()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="E-mail"
      formControlName="email"
    >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Senha"
      formGroupName="senha"
    >
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro estava ocorrendo porque no template da app o formControlName para o campo "senha", estava definido como formGroupName="senha" sendo que o correto seria formControlName="senha", isso ocorreu devido a um descuido com o auto-complete. Vale o aprendizado para verificar sempre a estrutura do reactive-form no template para evitar este tipo de erro.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Senha"
      formControlName="senha">
  </div>
```

Detalhes sobre Reactive Forms na [documentação](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) oficial do Angular.